# How can get the data from azure monitoring tab using the sdk (or powershell)

Tags: azure

I'm trying to monitor all our resources in a single place and after reading the msdn pages on monitoring web apps and cloud services and azure sql databases i can't seem to understand how to query azure (thorugh the SDK or powershell) to give me the same data i can see in the azure monitoring page.

is there some programattic way to get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't an easy answer to this. There isn't one API where you can fetch all the data: it's mostly service specific.

A couple of pointers:

- Metrics for web sites, web/worker roles and VMs can be accessed through the metrics API. See here: https://convective.wordpress.com/2014/06/22/using-azure-monitoring-service-with-azure-virtual-machines/
- Metrics for SQL Database are available through the [sys.resource_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269979.aspx) and [sys.dm_db_resource_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn800981.aspx) DMVs.
- Windows Azure Diagnostics (for web/worker roles) performance counters can be fetched though the table storage API, in the wadperformancecounterstable table.

There are probably API's for other services as well. I've built a tool myself that fetches data from a couple of these services, and can both plot it and expose it through a unified API, see: https://github.com/WadGraphEs/AzurePlot

Comment: i actually encountered your tool and service about a day after i asked this question, it is amazing. however since i'm more comfortable with python ill proably create my own using python instead.